# my own grails hosting

Tags: tomcat, grails, hosting

if i have a server machine with tomcat etc. How could i create well hosting for myself only. I mean if i would have several sites on one tomcat? If it possible to create stable environment with that without needing to restarting whole server when uploading new code to particular application on the tomcat? I just know that it is almost impossible with classic Java to have several sites which would be online 24x7 if someone changes some code on one of the application. It is not so easy as with ruby on rails right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong. It's actually [quite easy to redeploy a running application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application) in Tomcat, and other applications are not affected.

The main problem with this is [classloader leaks](http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java) in applications, which can eventually lead to an `OutOfMemoryError` and require a restart.

Comment: yes, it is interesting. then i should make 'reloading'-tests for all my applications on the server to be sure that everything ok before uploading new code. a little more work to do.

Answer (score 0):

With Grails your ability to hot deploy will be gated by your Perm Gen settings.  I have Hudson auto-building to an environment that has been stable for weeks - the perm gen settings I use are:

```
-XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```